# THREE.js—Fit texture to scaled plane

Tags: three.js, textures, texture-mapping

I am trying to create a Plane, which is resizable and displays the webcam's video stream.

I have this:

```
 const
   video = document.createElement('video'), 
   mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
     new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1),
     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()
   )
 ;

 let stream = null;

 mesh.material.map = this.material.map = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);

 async startStream () {
   const
    { x:width, y:height } = this.scale, 
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
        width: { ideal: width },
        height: { ideal: height }
      }
    });

    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
    return stream;
 }

 async stopStream () { ... }

 function onResize(width, height) {
   stopStream();
   mesh.scale.set(width, height, 1);
   stream = await startStream();
 }
```

The webcam can be seen on the Plane, but the video is not scaled correctly. I guess that is because the mesh is scaled. So how can I fit the video/texture on the scaled plane?

Comment: Does this thread answer your question? https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-fit-the-texture-to-the-plane/12017

Comment: looks good, gonna check...